# Catch error thrown by require in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I want to call a function `f` on another contract from a contract. The beginning of `f` has a `require` statement that I will not always meet. Is there a way to catch/handle errors with solidity without having the whole tx fail? I know I could check what’s in the require statement beforehand so please don’t suggest this. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no catch. If a `require` condition fails, the transaction will be rolled back.